# React.js working code breaks on re-render

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, checked

I have a weird bug, where my code works on first attempt, but breaks on page re-render.
I've created a filter function using an object with filter names and array of filter values:

```
const filterOptions = {
    'size': ['s', 'm', 'l'],
    'color': ['black', 'white', 'pink', 'beige'],
    'fit': ['relaxed fit','slim fit', 'skinny fit', 'oversize'],
    'pattern': ['patterned', 'spotted', 'solid color'],
    'material': ['wool', 'cotton', 'leather', 'denim', 'satin']
}
```

The idea was to create a separate object with all the values and corresponding 'checked' attribute and than use it to check if checkbox is checked:

```
 const [checkedValue, setCheckedValue] = useState({})

 useEffect(() => {
  const filterValuesArray = Object.values(filterOptions).flat()
  filterValuesArray.map(filter => setCheckedValue(currentState => ({...currentState, [filter]: { ...currentState[filter], checked: false }})))}, [])
```

FilterValue here is array of values from FilterOptions:

```
<div className='popper'>
        {filterValue.map(value => {
            return (
              <div key={`${value}`} className='popper-item'>
                <label className='popper-label'>{value}</label>
                <input onChange={handleCheckbox} checked={checkedValue[value].checked} type='checkbox' value={value} className="popper-checkbox" />
              </div>
            )}
        )}
       </div>
```

There is onChange function as wel, which could be a part of problem:

```
const handleCheckbox = (event) => {
const value = event.target.value;
setCheckedValue({...checkedValue, [value]: { ...checkedValue[value], checked: !checkedValue[value].checked }})
if(activeFilters.includes(value)) {
  const deleteFromArray = activeFilters.filter(item => item !== value)
  setActiveFilters(deleteFromArray)
} else {
  setActiveFilters([...activeFilters, value])
}}
```

I've tried keeping filterOptions in parent component and in Context, but it gives exactly the same result. It always work as planned on first render, and on next render it shows this error, until you delete the checked attribute of input. I've noticed that on re-render the 'checkedValue' object returns as empty, but I can't find out why. Would be really helpful if somebody could explain me a reason.

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'checked')

Edit: full code looks like this:

Parent Component

```
const Filter = () => {
  return (
        <div className='filter'>
            <div className="price-filter">
                <p>Price: </p>
                <Slider onChange={handleSliderChange} value={[min, max]} valueLabelDisplay="on" disableSwap style={{width:"70%"}} min={0} max={250} />  
            </div>
            <Divider />
            <ul className='filter-list'>
                {Object.entries(filterOptions).map((filter, i) => {
                    return (
                        <Fragment key={`${filter[0]}${i}`}>
                            <FilterOption className='filter-option' filterName={filter[0]} filterValue={filter[1]} />
                            <Divider key={`${i}${Math.random()}`} />
                        </Fragment>
                    )
                })}
            </ul>
        </div>   
    )
}
```

Child Component

```
const FilterOption = ({ filterName, filterValue }) => {
  const { checkedValue, setCheckedValue, activeFilters, setActiveFilters, filterOptions } = useContext(FilterContext)
  
  useEffect(() => {
    const filterValuesArray = Object.values(filterOptions).flat()
    filterValuesArray.map(filter => setCheckedValue(currentState => ({...currentState, [filter]: { ...currentState[filter], checked: false }})))
  }, [])

const handleCheckbox = (event) => {
    const value = event.target.value;
    setCheckedValue({...checkedValue, [value]: { ...checkedValue[value], checked: !checkedValue[value].checked }})
    if(activeFilters.includes(value)) {
      const deleteFromArray = activeFilters.filter(item => item !== value)
      setActiveFilters(deleteFromArray)
    } else {
      setActiveFilters([...activeFilters, value])
    }
  }

return (
  <div className='popper' key={filterName}>
            {filterValue.map(value => {
                return (
                  <div key={`${value}`} className='popper-item'>
                    <label className='popper-label'>{value}</label>
                    <input onChange={handleCheckbox} checked={checkedValue[value].checked} type='checkbox' value={value} className="popper-checkbox" />
                  </div>
                )}
            )}
   </div>
)
```

Comment: Where is `filterValue` coming from?

Comment: It comes as array of values of filterOptions from parent component. It was passed as a prop and than destructured. So 'map' basically iterates through every value of filterOptions.

Comment: Could you post the code of the whole component please? (it will be easier to understand the logic).

Comment: Sure thing, full code of both components is added.

Comment: Well first check for `checkedValue[value]` to be defined using `checkedValue[value]?.checked`

Comment: It worked. Thank you a lot. Still cant comprehend why it worked only on first page render and then stopped.